# FileReader: Object is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, filereader

My code -

```
$selectFile = $('<input type="file">');

$selectFile.click(function () {
            this.value = null;
});      
$selectFile.change(function(event){
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.readAsDataURL(event.target.files[0]);
    reader.onloadend(function(e){
        alert(e.result);
    });                           
});
```

I am getting object is not a function error at `reader.onloadend` line.

Can anyone help please.

Comment: Did you use Rhino lib?

Comment: No im not using Rhino. Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change your `onloadend` method to `onload`. Also you need to set it to a function, not a parameter. To get the url/data you want use `e.target.result` not just `e.result`. Finally, I'd place the `readAsDataURL` after setting the method to make sure that it fires.

```
$selectFile.change(function(event){
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function(e){
        alert(e.target.result);
    };             
    reader.readAsDataURL(event.target.files[0]);              
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/RK7Fc/2/)

Comment: I think onloadend is also good (while change the paramter to function)  $selectFile.change(function(event){
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onloadend = function(e){
        alert(e.target.result);
    };             
    reader.readAsDataURL(event.target.files[0]);              
});